# Deserializing JSON file, No output appearing

Tags: c#, json, parsing, debugging, deserialization

been trying to deserialize a certain JSON File Structured as follows

```
[
  {
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "Input": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "Input": "DEF "
      },
      {
        "Input": "GHI"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to print the ABC, DEF, GHI to my debugging output window for now, but I am getting no result. my C# code is as follows:

```
public partial class InputArray
{
    [JsonProperty("Inputs")]
    public List<InputObject> Inputs { get; set; }
}

public partial class InputObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Input")]
    public string Input { get; set; }
}

public static void LoadJson()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("input.json"))
    {
        var json = r.ReadToEnd();
        var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InputObject>>(json);


        foreach (var item in items)
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Input);
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried a few different solutions on Stack overflow to no success.

Comment: Shouldn't you be deserializing `List<InputArray>`?

Comment: Voting to close as this seems to be a typo.

Comment: var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputArray>(json); gives me a User-Unhandled Exception

Comment: [Works for me](https://rextester.com/EPT84870).

Comment: There must be something else I'm missing, thank you for trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your JSON carefully. The root is an array, as denoted by the outermost `[]`.

Inside the array, there is an object, which is represented by your `InputArray` class. Note that this is not your `InputObject` class.

You should deserialise `List<InputArray>` instead.

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InputArray>>(json);
```

Then, you need to use nested loops to loop through the items:

```
   foreach (var inputArray in items) {
        foreach (var inputObject in inputArray.Inputs) {
            Console.WriteLine(inputObject.Input);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your classes should be like

```
public class InputObject
{
    public string Input { get; set; }
}

public class InputArray
{
    public List<InputObject> Inputs { get; set; }
}
```

and you should serialize like below

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InputArray>>(json);
```